# ol7/ol-sidebar: UncaughtSyntaxError: The requested module '/ol-sidebar.js' does not provide an export named 'default' ALTHOUGH export default declared

Tags: javascript, export, openlayers

I receive an

Uncaught Syntaxerror: The requested module '/node_modules/ol-sidebar/dist/ol-sidebar.js?v=51b58510' does not provide an export named 'default' although I declared an default export.

main.js:

```
import Sidebar from './node_modules/ol-sidebar/dist/ol-sidebar';

/* ... some more code in here */

var sidebar = new Sidebar({});
```

ol-sidebar.js:

```
import Control from 'ol/control/Control.js'

export default class Sidebar extends Control {
   /*... some more code in here */
}
```

Why does the SyntaxError still appear? I'm quite confused..

Thank you in advance for any relevant idea how to solve this.

Best,
Kim

---

Already tried:

- Change the export default code as follows:

ol-sidebar.js:

```
import Control from 'ol/control/Control.js'
class Sidebar extends Control {
}
export default Sidebar;
```

corresponding main.js:

```
import Sidebar from './node_modules/ol-sidebar/dist/ol-sidebar'
```

- Tried the named export as follows:

ol-sidebar.js:

```
import Control from 'ol/control/Control.js'
export class Sidebar extends Control {
}
```

corresponding main.js:

```
import {Sidebar} from './node_modules/ol-sidebar/dist/ol-sidebar'
```

Resulted in an uncaught SyntaxError stating that the named export 'Sidebar' is unknown.

- Interestingly, yesterday, it worked as expected as no export was declared in ol-sidebar.js and the import of the module in main.js was done using the statement `import Sidebar from './node_modules/ol-sidebar/dist/ol-sidebar'; but today, this no longer works (PC reboot inbetween)!?`

Comment: It seems like the cache was the problem, after deactivating it, it worked properly with adding "export { Sidebar };" at the end of ol-sidebar.js and importing the module in main.js via "import { Sidebar } from './node_modules/ol-sidebar/dist/ol-sidebar.js';".